# Show that $ \lim_{(x,y) \to 0} \frac {|x|^ \alpha |y|^ \beta} {|x|^ \gamma + |y|^ \delta} \text {exists} \iff \alpha/\gamma + \beta/\delta > 1.$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Ted Shifrin on this site posed an interesting problem to me: show that

$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac {|x|^ \alpha |y|^ \beta} {|x|^ \gamma + |y|^ \delta} \text {exists} \iff \frac\alpha\gamma + \frac\beta\delta > 1, \,\,\,\,\text{where } \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta >0$$

I think I've got the $(\Leftarrow)$ direction as follows: assume WLOG that $\gamma \leq \delta$. Then switch to polar coordinates and get

$$\frac {r^ {\alpha + \beta} (*) } {r^\gamma (1(*) + r^{\delta - \gamma}(*))},$$

where $(*)$ represents some trig stuff that is bounded near zero.

**Edit:** I need to make sure that $(1(*) + r^{\delta - \gamma}(*))$ is bounded below here.

The other direction is giving me some trouble. It seems we need a lower bound for the fraction (something to force to zero), and I'm not sure where to find one. In particular, I'm not sure what to do with the denominator. Any ideas?

Comment: **Hint**:if we let $\large{\lim_{(x,y) \to 0} \frac {|x|^ \alpha |y|^ \beta} {|x|^ \gamma + |y|^ \delta} \text {exists}}$ exactly  its limit   in all path is exist
know let $x=y $

Comment: Right, if we let $x=2y$, say, then what do we do with the denominator?

Comment: For the $\Leftarrow$ direction, I think you need to elaborate on "some trig stuff that is bounded near zero". For the numerator this is enough, but you need to prove that the denominator is bounded below or something of the sort. In fact, I think you cannot prove this by ignoring the trigonometric parts: otherwise, you would have proven that $$\frac{\alpha + \beta}{\min(\gamma, \delta)} > 1$$ sufficed for the limit to exist.

Comment: That's a good point. I need to fix some of the details there.

Comment: By the way, the $\Rightarrow$ direction is actually easier. Suppose the said limit exists, and consider the particular case where $|x| = t^\delta, |y| = t^\gamma$ ($t \to 0$). What do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the $(\Leftarrow)$ direction, we first note that
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to 0} \frac{|x|^\alpha |y|^\beta}{|x|^\gamma + |y|^\delta} = \lim_{r_1,r_2 \to 0^+} \frac{r^\alpha_1 r^\beta_2}{r^\gamma_1 + r^\delta_2} = \lim_{t_1,t_2 \to 0^+} \frac{t^{\alpha\delta}_1 t^{\beta\gamma}_2}{t^{\gamma\delta}_1 + t^{\gamma\delta}_2}, $$
since a sequence $(t_n, s_n) \to (0,0)$ if and only if $(t^\delta_n, s^\gamma_n) \to (0,0)$

Now for the rightmost limit, your basic argument works: by switching to polar coordinates we have
$$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{r^{\alpha \delta + \beta \gamma}\left|\sin(\theta)^{(\beta \gamma)} \cos(\theta)^{(\alpha \delta)}\right|}{r^{\gamma \delta} \left(\left|\sin(\theta)^{(\gamma \delta)}\right| + \left|\cos(\theta)^{(\gamma \delta)}\right|\right)}, $$

which we can easily show to converge (to zero) if $\alpha \delta + \beta \gamma > \gamma \delta$.

For the ($\Rightarrow$) direction, assume that the said limit exists. Then, in particular, this limit also exists:
$$\lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{(t^\delta)^\alpha (t^\gamma)^\delta}{(t^\delta)^\gamma + (t^\gamma)^\delta},$$
which clearly exists only if $\alpha \delta + \beta \gamma > \gamma \delta$.

EDIT: The last limit exists if $\alpha \delta + \beta \gamma \geq \gamma \delta$.

To show that we can't have $\alpha \delta + \beta \gamma = \gamma \delta$, notice that while in this case the above limit is $\frac12$, we also have other "subsequences" converging to zero: let $N$ be such that $\beta N > \gamma$ and $\delta N > \gamma$. Then
$$ \frac{t^\alpha (t^N)^\beta}{t^\gamma + (t^N)^\delta} \approx \frac{t^\alpha (t^N)^\beta}{t^\gamma} \to 0 $$
Thus the limit does not exist when $\alpha \delta + \beta \gamma = \gamma \delta.$

Comment: Thanks for your solution! You have no idea how much that problem was bothering me.

Comment: I notice we can generalize this to $n$ dimensions by noting that the factor in the denominator which is here represented by $|\sin(\theta)|^{(\gamma \delta)} + |\cos(\theta)|^{(\gamma \delta)}$ (I think we want the bars on the inside, right?) is (in any dimension $\mathbb{R}^n$) the $\infty$ norm of a vector whose $2/(\gamma\delta)$-norm is $1$, so it is bounded below for all $\theta$.

Comment: By generalizing to $n$ dimensions do you mean the following? 

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x_1^{\alpha_1} \ldots x_n^{\alpha_n}}{x_1^{\beta_1} + \ldots + x_n^{\beta_n}} \text{ exists } \Leftrightarrow \sum_i \frac{\alpha_i}{\beta_i} > 1$$

Comment: Yes, exactly. I think we'd make the substitution $x_i^{\alpha_i}  \leftrightarrow x_i^{\alpha_i \prod_{j\neq i}\beta_j}$.

Comment: I note that a consequence of this generalization would be that $$\frac { x_1^{\alpha_1} \dotsb x_n^{\alpha_n} } {\|x\|^p}$$ converges iff $\sum \alpha_i > p$, since $$ \frac1n (|x_1|^p + \dotsb + |x_n|^p) \leq \|x\|^p \leq n^{p/2}(|x_1|^p + \dotsb + |x_n|^p). $$

Comment: About your previous comment, that would be the $1$-norm, not the $\infty$ norm, of such a vector. About the last comment, I believe this would be a consequence (provided the generalized result is true) regardless of the norm you're using, because all norms in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent.

Comment: Right, the 1 norm! Thank you.