# Easiest way to show $ \lim \limits_{x\to 0} \frac { |x_1|^{\alpha_1} \dotsb |x_n|^{\alpha_n} } {\| x\|^p} \text { exists } \iff \sum{\alpha_i} > p$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

What is the easiest way to show $$ \lim \limits_{x\to0} \frac { |x_1|^{\alpha_1} \dotsb |x_n|^{\alpha_n} } {\| x\|^p} \text { exists } \iff \sum{\alpha_i} > p, \,\,\,\,\text {   for } \alpha_i >0 \text { ?} $$

One way would be to quote [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451867/show-that-lim-x-y-to-0-frac-x-alpha-y-beta-x-gamma-y) result, which gives a similar theorem except that the denominator is $\sum |x_i|^{\beta_i}$, and take $\beta_i=p$ for all $i$, and note that the $2$ norm and the $p$ norm are equivalent, so $\|x\|_p^p \lesssim \|x\|_2^p$ and vice-versa.

Anyone know a simpler way?

We'd like to maybe switch to spherical coordinates and claim that the trigonometric factor we're left with in the numerator is bounded above, but why is it bounded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $${{{\sqrt {x_1^2 +  \cdots  + x_n^2} }}}\leq\sqrt n \max_{1\leq i\leq n}|x_i|$$

And for each $i$ $$\left| {{x_i}} \right| \leqslant \sqrt {x_1^2 +  \cdots  + x_n^2} $$

Thus, for one $$0 \leqslant \frac{{|{x_1}{|^{{\alpha _1}}} \cdots |{x_n}{|^{{\alpha _n}}}}}{{{{\left\| {\bf{x}} \right\|}^p}}} \leqslant \frac{{{{\left\| {\bf{x}} \right\|}^{\sum {{\alpha _i}} }}}}{{{{\left\| {\bf{x}} \right\|}^p}}}={\left\| {\bf{x}} \right\|^{\sum {{\alpha _i} - p} }}$$

and this proves one direction. For the other direction, your idea is fine. In fact, as Sami cleverly points out, setting $x_i=t$ works just as fine.

Comment: Thank you! I think that direction is the hard one. The other one we can show pretty easily.

Comment: @EricAuld What would the proof be?

Comment: Is the first inequality missing a $\sqrt{n}?$.

Comment: @Alex I think I edited it before seeing your comment.

Comment: Well, I would take first the case $\sum \alpha_i = p$, and take $x_i = 2x_1 \,\, \forall i \neq 1$, then take $x_i = 3x_1 \,\, \forall i \neq 1$, and show they're different as they go to zero. Then if $\sum \alpha_i < p$... oh well, you've already indicated it above.

Comment: @EricAuld That looks promising, yes.

Answer (score 3):

$(\Leftarrow)$ Notice that
$$|x_i|\leq ||x||$$
so
 $$0 \leq\frac { |x_1|^{\alpha_1} \dotsb |x_n|^{\alpha_n} } {\| x\|^p}\leq ||x||^{\sum\alpha_i-p}\to0 $$
$(\Rightarrow)$

If 
$$|x_i|=t,\quad\forall i$$
then
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac { |x_1|^{\alpha_1} \dotsb |x_n|^{\alpha_n} } {\| x\|^p}=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{t^{\sum_i\alpha_i}}{nt^p}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1}{n}t^{\sum_i\alpha_i-p}<\infty\iff \sum_i\alpha_i-p\geq0$$
and if $\sum_i\alpha_i=p$ then the above limit is $\frac{1}{n}$ and by choosing $x_1=0$ the limit becomes $0$ so if the limit exists then $\sum_i\alpha_i-p>0$ QED

Comment: Good proof! In the last inset line, second equation, should it be $n^{p/2}$?

Comment: Sorry which equation?

Comment: Should it be $$\dotsb = \lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac {t^{\sum_i \alpha_i}} {n^{p/2}t^p} \text { ? }$$

Comment: I worked with the $p$ norm so $||x||^p=\sum x_i^p$.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane It seems the OP is working with the $2$-norm (i.e. the usual Euclidean norm).

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Personally I  thought the expression contains the $p$-norm but somehow it is not a big thing to change if we understand the principle of calculus.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane I know, it is slightly irrelevant. =)

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. The superscript was an exponent, and the subscript was for the type of norm. Good thing it doesn't matter!

Comment: Excellent work, Sami!